# How to split a row in array?

Tags: php, arrays, split

Example :

```
Array
    (
          [0] => "example.fr", "2013-08-24", "test"
          [1] => "toto.com, "2014-10-01", "test2"
    )
```

How can I do to split this array every comma ? I would like to get every word in quotes into a variable like this :

```
    $var1= "example.fr";
    $var2= "2013-08-24";
    $var3 = "test";
....
```

EDIT: The structure of the array is GOOD ! Every element is enclosed in quotes in ONLY one array ! Like CSV file

Comment: Can you check the syntax and edit the question as your problem?

Comment: Random guess: is this supposed to be CSV data?

Comment: This will throw ERROR -> "toto.com, "2014-10-01", "test2 ..replace it with "toto.com", "2014-10-01", "test2"

Comment: There is no syntax problem ! Is like CSV data yes, so every element is enclosed in quotes

Comment: So parse it using a CSV parser...?!

Comment: I can't because data are not in a CSV file ! I use cURL to get it in a web site but when I retrieve and display them I get an array formatted like a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent a CSV parser, use the existing functionality.

From PHP 5.3+:

```
$parsed = array_map('str_getcsv', $array);
```

http://php.net/str_getcsv

Before 5.3:

```
$fh = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');

$parsed = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
    ftruncate($fh, 0);
    fwrite($fh, $row);
    rewind($fh);
    $parsed[] = fgetcsv($fh);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: I use the PHP 5.2.16 version so I am in the second case but I don't open a csv file, I just retrieve data which are in csv format

Comment: @PANPELOPE So use my solution above! It uses the `fgetcsv` function to parse CSV data **from an array**.

Comment: `fgetcsv` needs a *file pointer* to read from. Since your data is not in a file, you have a problem. To circumvent that, we're creating a *fake file* using `fopen('php://temp')`. `php://temp` is a special stream wrapper which just temporarily stores data in memory; but it gives you a "real file pointer". So the code opens a fake file, writes the CSV data into it (just a copy in memory, no actual file involved), then passes this file pointer to `fgetcsv` which reads it like a CSV file. It's a workaround to use `fgetcsv` with data not coming from a file.

Comment: @PANPELOPE The only thing for you to add in this code is your `$array`, the other parts work as is.

Comment: I try it and it works, I have succeeded in splitting my array. Thank for this solution and for the information concerning `fopen('php://temp')` :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you can access the array elements and assign them to variables like this:

```
$var1 = $arrayName[0][0];
$var2 = $arrayName[0][1];
$var3 = $arrayName[0][2];
```

I can't tell from you're question if the array is holding a single string per index or if it is a 2D array. If it's holding strings then see realshadow's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
array("example.fr, 2013-08-24, test")

list($var1, $var2, $var3) = explode(', ', $array[0]); // or current
```

Comment: I did not really get the array structure as described in question. So as an example, I made its value to string (in question its even missing some quotes). And since there were already good answers, I thought I might add this one for completition

Comment: The array structure is exactly as I wrote : `Array
    (
          [0] => "example.fr", "2013-08-24", "test"
          [1] => "toto.com, "2014-10-01", "test2"
    )` .

Answer (score 0):

Use explode on every item of the array: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: You can not use explode on a array

Comment: RTFM: I never said, you can do that: You can use explode on EVERY ITEM of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your syntax is quite right to create a multidimensional array, consider this example:

```
$myArray = array( array("example.fr", "2013-08-24", "test"),
           array("toto.com, "2014-10-01", "test2"));
```

Now you have an array of arrays and can iterate over each.

If you know for sure how many items you have in each array then you can explode the array into its constituents, but if you don't know before hand than iterating will see you through.

Comment: I don't want to create a multidimensional array, I just want to handle a simple array with several keys as I wrote

Comment: Each key value pair in your example is an array, are you sure that each element should be enclosed in quotes or should each line be enclosed in quotes once? `[0] => "example.fr, 2013-08-24, test"`

Comment: Each element is enclosed in quotes as I wrote

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure with the structure, but let me know if this is what ur looking for, happy to help u then -

```
<?php

$myarr = array( array("example.fr", "2013-08-24", "test"),array("toto.com", "2014-10-01", "test2"));

foreach($myarr as $breakpart)
{
echo "<pre>";     
print_r($breakpart);
}
```

**OUTPUT** -

```
Array
(
    [0] => example.fr
    [1] => 2013-08-24
    [2] => test
)

Array
(
    [0] => toto.com
    [1] => 2014-10-01
    [2] => test2
)
```

Codepad Link - [codepad.org/6S7EMldq](http://codepad.org/6S7EMldq)